# How do I change the celery ForkPoolWorker's process name?

Tags: celery

In celery, when using multiprocessing concurrency (i.e., a ForkPoolWorker process), how do I control the process name of each such ForkPoolWorker process?

I need to name each such process so that anywhere its name appears (top, Datadog, GCP observability, etc), it is clear which amongst several celery workers that specific ForkPoolWorker process belongs to.

Currently, the names are vague (e.g., `[celeryd: celery@joints-io-1:ForkPoolWorker-1]` is seen in Datadog or GCP observability) until one can get at the parent process (e.g, using `top`'s forest view):

```
joints      23:12:31    1811    1811     863 S     \_ [celeryd: celery@joints-io-1:MainProcess] -active- (worker -A joints.daemons.update.updateworker --queues=updd --pre
joints      23:12:29    1839    1811     863 S         \_ [celeryd: celery@joints-io-1:ForkPoolWorker-1]
joints      23:12:29    1844    1811     863 Sl        \_ [celeryd: celery@joints-io-1:ForkPoolWorker-2]
joints      23:12:29    1849    1811     863 S         \_ [celeryd: celery@joints-io-1:ForkPoolWorker-3]
joints      23:12:29    1855    1811     863 Sl        \_ [celeryd: celery@joints-io-1:ForkPoolWorker-4]
joints      23:12:28    1862    1811     863 S         \_ [celeryd: celery@joints-io-1:ForkPoolWorker-5]
joints      23:12:28    1869    1811     863 Sl        \_ [celeryd: celery@joints-io-1:ForkPoolWorker-6]
joints      23:12:28    1880    1811     863 S         \_ [celeryd: celery@joints-io-1:ForkPoolWorker-7]
joints      23:12:28    1893    1811     863 Sl        \_ [celeryd: celery@joints-io-1:ForkPoolWorker-8]
```

where finally one could see the parent process cmd line has:

`worker -A joints.daemons.update.updateworker`

making the task name apparent.

However, using `top` is not always relevant because monitoring scores of processes via Datadog or GCP only shows records for the bland process name which is nearly useless when seen a single process name at a time. One cannot tell which process is using a lot of CPU, memory, disk I/O, etc in Datadog or GCP observability.

Comment: What you can easily change is the `celery@joints-io-1` part (name of the node), which can be specified using the `-n` switch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `celery worker -n name` [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74479229/how-do-i-change-the-celery-forkpoolworkers-process-name?noredirect=1#comment131489420_74479229) by @DejanLekic

However, be aware that if you are using `supervisord`, then it is sensitive to the formatting used as an arg to `-n` within its `command=...` key/value and will reject `-n foo@%h`, `-n "foo@h"`, etc but will accept `-n foo`. The effect will be that you will have a process name in `ps` or `top` of:

`[celeryd: celery@foo:ForkPoolWorker-1]`